# I get this error when programming the flutter android app?

Tags: android, flutter

The plugin `facebook_audience_network` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Android resource compilation failed
> /Users/mac/Desktop/main_files/source/news_app/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-h??????dp-v13/values-h??????dp-v13.xml: error: invalid configuration 'h??????dp-v13'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Android resource compilation failed
> /Users/mac/Desktop/main_files/source/news_app/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-sw??????dp-v13/values-sw??????dp-v13.xml: error: invalid configuration 'sw??????dp-v13'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

This is for the new flutter update. There is nothing you can do. Either use an other package or ask the package developer to fix the problem. This error is after version 2.5 of the flutter.

or you can downgrade flutter version.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `pubspec.yaml` file and make sure you are using the latest version of the `facebook_audience_network` which is `facebook_audience_network: ^0.9.0` then check the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_audience_network) if you doing the android configurations correctly.
the do a `flutter upgrade`.

Comment: flutter upgrade
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 2.5.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 18116933e7 (4 days ago) • 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
Engine • revision d3ea636dc5
Tools • Dart 2.14.4